# Prove continuity of a function from $S^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, algebraic-topology, continuity, necklace-and-bracelets

Given an interval $k$-coloring of $[0,1]$, define a function $f: S^k \to \Bbb R^k$ as follows ($S^k$ is the $k$-sphere).
Let $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_{k+1})$ be a point on the $k$-sphere $S^k$. Define $z = (z_0,z_1,...z_{k+1})$ as follows :

$$z_0 = 0$$
$$\forall j>0, z_j = \sum_{i=1}^{j}x_i^2$$

For $1 < j < k$, define $f_j(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \operatorname{sign}(x_i)m_j(i)$,
where $m_j(i)$ is the measure of the $j$th color in the segment $[z_{i-1},z_i]$. Finally, $f(x) = (f_1(x),...,f_k(x))$.

This definition can be found on page $2$ of [The Borsuk-Ulam Theorem and bisection of necklaces](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-098-04/S0002-9939-1986-0861764-9/S0002-9939-1986-0861764-9.pdf).

How to prove that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the $z_j$ are continuous.
The $m_j$ are also continuous (even Lipschitz with constant $1$).
Hence discontinuity can only occur when some $x_i=0$ from the sign function in the $i$th summand. But in a neighbourhood of such points, $m_j(i)$ is $O(x^2)$,

In effect, $f$ is continuous essentially for the same reason that $x\mapsto |x|\cdot x$ is ...